# openssl cross-sign non-self signed certificate

Tags: openssl

I want to cross-sign a third-party certificate (`third-party-client.crt`) with my own root ca (`r1`).

To do this, I use

```
openssl x509 -in third-party-client.crt -CA /etc/pki/r1/ca.crt -CAkey /etc/pki/r1/private/ca.key -out third-party-client-cross-signed.crt -set_serial 1000
```

When I don't have the CA that issued the third party certificate in my local CA store, I get the following error:

```
Getting CA Private Key
/CN=Third Party Client Cert
error with certificate - error 20 at depth 0
unable to get local issuer certificate
/CN=Third Party Client Cert
error with certificate - error 21 at depth 0
unable to verify the first certificate
error with certificate to be certified - should be self signed
```

After adding the certificate that issued the third party cert to the CA store, I still get the following error:

```
Getting CA Private Key
error with certificate to be certified - should be self signed
```

How can I cross-sign a non-self-signed third-party certificate? (Ideally, without first importing the issuer ca into the CA store)

Comment: Use version 1.1.1 (or lower, but those are officially EOL); it gives the verify errors, but proceeds anyway. Both older and current code has a comment saying the cert 'should be self-signed' so it appears this check was always intended but just didn't quite work before -- although I don't see _why_ it should. (It might be an analogy to issuing from a CSR, which _is_ required to be selfsigned, but I consider that a wrong analogy.) I was going to also point you to https://serverfault.com/questions/1103302 but I see that's unnecessary.

Comment: Atleast on 1.1.1n, it doesn't work. (An empty out-file is created though)
Do you know in which specific version it still works? (Still, this obviously isn't a great solution)

The best path forward (atleast knowing *why* it behaves this way) would probably be the openssl-users list?

Comment: I have tried with 1.1.0j and got the same issue (it creates an empty `-out` file)

Comment: I hit the same error on a Windows version of “OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022”. I tried exactly the same command on Ubuntu’s current “OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022)” and it worked without problems.

Comment: @Mormegil I tried it again `OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022` on ubuntu, but ran into the exact same errors mentioned in my OP. Are you sure that the third party certificate you are signing is indeed not self-signed?